# Laravel 5 - how to perform left join on same table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

In my application, there's two tables at the moment: `users` and `employees`. The latter is simply a profile table for the boilerplate `users` table that ships with Laravel.

I have two foreign keys inside of `employees`, one is `user_id` that points to `id` on `users` table. So basically, the profile data of the registered user. The second foreign key in `employees` is `manager_id`. That is the id of the person who is the manager of an employee. Some users are managers and have a blank `manager_id` field.

I want to retrieve the row from my `Employee` model where the `user_id` matches the `manager_id`and then send them all to my view, where they will see the `first_name` and `last_name` of the manager. At the moment I see the manager ID instead of their name.

Comment: Why do you have two tables? Couldn't you just add manager_id to the users table and make an inner join of the users table?

Comment: Could you also provide what you have tried, your current code?

Comment: @RasmusRosengren: `$employees = Employee::all(); $manager = Employee::find(1)->where('userid', '=', 'manager');`

Comment: `Employee::find(1)` returns the row with where the `employees.id` is `1`

Comment: I'm not saying it's correct.

Comment: Do you have a Employee and a User model?

Comment: Yes, they are both there

Comment: Do you really need 2 tables for this? Does the `employees` table only contain user_id and manager_id?

Comment: I'm trying to learn joins in Laravel via these two simple tables. There are `first_name` and `last_name` as well, as I have mentioned in the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122745/discussion-between-rasmus-rosengren-and-omrakhur).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample LeftJoin =>

```
DB::connection('testing')->table('table1 as t1')
->select('t1.column, t2.column')
->leftJoin('table2 as t2','t2.client_id','=','t1.id')
->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try some thing like this:

```
$users = DB::table('users t1')
->join('users t2', 't1.id', '=', 't2.user_id')
->select('your column list')
->get();
```

// here we are creating 2 aliases for users table which make it self join

Comment: shouldn't it be `leftJoin` instead of `join` ?

Comment: that's depends on your condition

Answer (score 0):

In your Employees model add the following method:

```
public function manager()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\User', 'id', 'manager_id');
}
```

You can then get the name of the Manager like this:

```
$employee = \App\Employee::find(1);
$manager = $employee->manager()->first();
$manager_name = $manager->name;
```